# Is there is a way to lock my USB port over the device physically?

Tags: windows, physical, ports

Is there is a way to lock my USB port over the device physically ?

For example I am connecting the USB mouse and keyboard on an public computer but I do not want anyone to remove them physically. I want to physically blocks these USB ports from unauthorized access in fact most airport use USB blockers for the public computer but I cannot find any images on or something relevant.

An other option will be to edit some configuration in the system to just identify these mouse and keyboard and do not  work with any other device?

Comment: http://www.kensington.com/kensington/us/us/p/1645/K67720US/usb-port-lock-with-square-cable-guard.aspx appears to do what you're after. First result - https://www.google.com/?q=lock+usb+port+keyboard

Answer (score 8):

The solution most often found in airports is to restrict access to the PC itself - placing it within a lockable case or kiosk.

Alternatively, epoxy resin is pretty good for sealing ports, whether or not they have a plug inserted (remember you will need to seal all ports an attacker could access)

Comment: Yeah, I almost missed that and was about to put "superglue works wonders"

Answer (score 1):

You can lock the usb ports for anything besides a certain hardware id and also by use. Even if someone is able to clone the keyboard id into another device, that device would only be usable if it's another keyboard. If you only want to. Disable data transfer, you can disable mass storage device, usb cdrom, ... And then you don't have to worry about changing the keyboard /mouse or installing a webcam. You can do all those tweaks from windows registry

Answer (score 0):

As Bob Watson pointed out, a simple google search gives you a solution for physical blocking.

Software like Symantec Endpoint Protection offer device blocking by ID (http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH106304).

Of course, someone determined enough could clone an allowed id to another device and be able to use it.

Moreover, a [keylogger](http://dx.com/p/usb-keyboard-keylogger-black-127262) device, that sits between the computer and the keyboard would go undetected.